# callback function for google.ads.search.Ads()

Tags: javascript, callback, adsense, google-custom-search

Following the docs on https://developers.google.com/custom-search-ads/docs/implementation-guide I created some code to retrieve ads on a search result page.

This code assumes that you place a container on your webpage where the function

```
new google.ads.search.Ads(pageOptions, adblock1, adblock2);
```

appends an iFrame to that *may* contain ads. I say MAY contain, because sometimes the iFrames stay empty.

Question:
Now I need to know whether there are any ads displayed in the containers or not. How do I do this?

- The call is asynchronous, so when should I initialise the check? (the google reference does not note a callback function)
- How do I check if there's an ad shown. Because with Javascript I can't look inside the iFrame.

Any suggestions welcome! :)

Regards,
Jorn

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am having issues with some of my ads and this would really help me handle error cases.

Answer (score 2):

the callback function, that maybe helps you is:

```
'noAdLoadedCallback':
  function(containerName, adsLoaded) {
      if (!adsLoaded) {
          try {
              ---- do something here ---
          }
          catch (e) {}
      }
  }
```

You can put this on each adblock.

Cheers
Nik

Answer (score 1):

Today I faced the same problem, and based on the response from @Niko Nik the solution that worked for me is the following one:

```
AppComponent.prototype.prepareAds = function (containerId, nOfAds, query) {
    var csa = window._googCsa || function () {};
    var self_1 = this;
    var pageOptions = {
        'pubId': this.gootleAdClient,
        'adtest': this.googleAdTest,
        'adLoadedCallback': function adLoadedCallback(containerName, adsLoaded) {
            self_1.adsLoaded[containerName] = adsLoaded;
        }
    };
    var adBlock = {
        'container': containerId,
        'width': '100%',
        'number': nOfAds
    };
    if (query) {
        pageOptions['query'] = query;
    }
    this.adsLoaded[containerId] = true;
    csa('ads', pageOptions, adBlock);
}
```

I found that `adLoadedCallback` has the advantadge that it's called when there are ads and when there are not (`adsLoaded` parameter is true when there are an false when there are not).

Answer (score 0):

You could always add a MutationObserver and wait for the iframe to be inserted, then check its height. If it's less than 30 pixels tall, it's probably empty.

I haven't seen any callbacks in the CSA code, but I have seen two undocumented options for ad blocks, `clicktrackUrl` and `linkTarget`. One is a url for a tracking pixel that's loaded when ads are clicked, the other acts like the target attribute on an a tag.